# Jwt creating token with null secretkey

Tags: php, authentication, jwt, secret-key

i am creating a jwt token ,i use secret key based on the platform which i am giving in my api request.Based on platforms in stored secret key in my config.now if i change platforms in my config then there should be an error while creating token as it will not get secret key but still its creating the token without secret key.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost/api/api/v1/atom/auth/createToken?key=d32121c70dda5edfgd1df6633fdb36c0&platform=M' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: refresh=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJBWVFMWjVITVFHRFQ4OEw5T0RZSUNJSVY2SFlIMkMwWCIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiYmN1TTR3WHJPODUyQW9mbXc9PV9DIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6IjMiLCJwbGF0Zm9ybSI6Ik0iLCJyZXF1ZXN0X3R5cGUiOiJyZWZyZXNoX3Rva2VuIiwiZXhwaXJlc19pbiI6MTY5NjQ3NzMxNn0.FVw5Skk29oyaS1jFj9TMvZFdvzFqHMYlUwVfgSE5zCc' \
--data-raw '{
    "client_id":"AYQLZ5HMQGDT88L9ODYICIIV6HYH2C0X",
    "username":"bcuM4wXrO852Aofmw==_C",
    "user_id":"3",
    "platform":"M"
}'
```

This is my token creation api, I am creating token for platform M which i passed in params.

```
$config['oauth_client_details'] = array(
    'D_A' => array('access_token_api_url' => 'atom/auth/createToken',
        'client_id' => 'AYQLZ5HMQGDT88L9ODYICIIV6HYH2C0X',
        'client_secret' => 'A@kamalshike@Tiwari&ayodhya!@#12987$%',
        
        'auth_token_expiry_in' => 604800,
        'refresh_token_expiry_in' => 1209600
    ))
```

This is my config as I am not having an config for platform M. I am getting blank secret key in my code.

```
 $this->authClientDetails = \Registry::get('config.oauth_client_details')[$this->_request_data['platform']];
```

I am getting blank in this variable which I am passing in below code:

```
$encoded_access_token = $this->jwtToken->encode($payload_data,$this->authClientDetails['client_secret'],'HS256');
```

Instead of giving me an error it's creating a token, I read the code which written in my JWT library. There is nothing in that code which says that $key is optional parameter.

How will i solve this?